# How do I clone an HTML element's style object using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to clone the style object of an element. This should allow me to reset the styles of said element after I change them.

For example:

```
el.style.left;      // 50px
curr_style.left;    // 50px;

/* 
Modify the elements style.
The cloned style should still hold the original properties from when it was cloned.
*/
el.style.left = '20px';
curr_style.left // should still return 50px.
```

I first tried to copy it by assigning a variable to the value of el.style. Unfortunately, this points to it by reference and any changes to the style are reflected in the cloned object.

My other attempt involved using jQuery's object extend method to create a copy as such:

```
var curr_style = $.extend( {}, el.style );
```

This doesn't seem to work as curr_style.left etc. return undefined.

Any help would be appreciated!

**I ended up doing this to retrieve each property:** (based on advice from @Raynos)

```
$.fn.getStyle = function(){
    var style,
    el = this[0];

    // Fallbacks for old browsers.
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        style = window.getComputedStyle( el );
    } else if (el.currentStyle) {
        style = $.extend(true, {}, el.currentStyle);
    } else {
        style = $.extend(true, {}, el.style);
    }

    // Loop through styles and get each property. Add to object.
    var styles = {};
    for( var i=0; i<style.length; i++){
        styles[ style[i] ] = style[ style[i] ];
    }

    return styles;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var curr_style;
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    curr_style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
} else if (el.currentStyle) {
    curr_style = $.extend(true, {}, el.currentStyle);
} else {
    throw "shit browser";
}
```

`style` has non-enumerable properties which makes `.extend` fall over. You want to use the `getComputedStyle` method to get the styles of an element.

You also want to support older versions of IE by extending `el.currentStyle` which does have enumerable properties.

The first argument (when set to `true`) tells jQuery to do a *deep* clone.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a step in the right direction. The problem I'm having is that it seems that the style object is not a fundamental javascript object. For example, inspecting the style object and the cloned object in firebug, they seem to have the same properties. Neither of them have a 'left' property but style.left will return a value whereas curr_style.left will not.

Comment: @AdamHutchinson the problem is that the properties of `style` are non-enumerable.

Comment: @Raynos is there any way to get around that?

Comment: @AdamHutchinson yes. Use `computedStyle` & `currentStyle` which have enumerable properties. (computedStyle also returns a new object so it's cool)

Comment: @Raynos It seems that changing el.style.left causes the value returned from curr_style.left to change even when using computedStyle

Comment: @AdamHutchinson :( Then do a deep clone on the `computedStyle`

Answer (score 5):

For the purpose of simply resetting styles, I'd suggest just using the [`cssText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSRule) (also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/cssRule.cssText)) property of the `style` object. This works in all major browsers and is nice and simple.

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/WpHme/

Example code:

```
// Store the original style
var originalCssText = el.style.cssText;

// Change a style property of the element
el.style.fontWeight = "bold";

// Now reset
el.style.cssText = originalCssText;
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

I'm planning on using the animate method of jQuery to perform the reset and only using certain properties from the style object.

Comment: @Adam: Fair enough then, my answer won't do. I'll leave it here anyway for anyone coming across this question in future who it may help.